# Having issues joing a table with a recursive function in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, join, union

I'm building a complex query but I have a problem...
Pratically, I retrieve a dates range from recursive function in sqlite:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(d)
AS (VALUES('2014-05-01')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date(d, '+1 day')
    FROM dates
    WHERE d < '2014-05-5')
SELECT d AS date FROM dates
```

This is the result:

```
2014-05-01
2014-05-02
2014-05-03
2014-05-04
2014-05-05
```

I would join this query on other query, about this:

```
select date_column, column1, column2 from table
```

This is the result:

```
2014-05-03  column_value1  column_value2
```

Finally, I would like to see a similar result in output (join first query and date_column of second query):

```
2014-05-01 |               |               |
2014-05-02 |               |               |
2014-05-03 | column_value1 | column_value2 |
2014-05-04 |               |               |
2014-05-05 |               |               |
```

How can I obtain this result?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's recommended to always have a dates table.

Comment: is the `with recrursive` using a reserved word as a pseudotable name?

Comment: @xQbert is a reserved word in sqlite

Comment: So does changing the name of the table eliminate the error?  I don't know what's not working so I'm not sure where to look yet :D  Other than it seems odd to name a table (pseudo or otherwise) a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply do something like this ?

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(d)
AS (VALUES('2014-05-01')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date(d, '+1 day')
    FROM dates
    WHERE d < '2014-05-5')
SELECT 
    dates.d AS date 
    ,table.column1
    ,table.column2
FROM dates
    left join table
        ON strftime("%Y-%m-%d", table.date_column) = dates.date
```

Perhaps you will need to convert your date...

Comment: Must I use strftime("%Y-%m-%d", table.date_column) ?

Comment: I'm cannot really know at the moment, you have to be sure that the dates `table.date_column` = `dates.date` are in the same format (text or date). `table.date_column` should be in date format I guess, so **NO**. If you need some specific helps give us your sqllite structure and a sample using sqlfiddle like : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cfeb2/1

Comment: table.date_column is datetime format (ex: 2014-05-05 00:00:00.000000)

Comment: My bad, yes you should do something like `ON strftime("%Y-%m-%d", table.date_column) = dates.date`

Comment: mmm, sorry for reopen the question but your query doesn't works... :-S

Comment: Can you give me a sqlfiddle, so I'll look at it to help you as much I can.

Comment: I tryied, but sqllite version of sqlfiddle still not support CTE. But I replaced it to show you how could it works : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6f221/13 If you are not sure, you can put the `strftime("%Y-%m-%d", _date_)` on both columns

Comment: Thanks man, you're awesome! I like your solution and it's a simple query. The "problem" is that I need change the range of dates programmatically. Do you think that I can build the query programmatically? :)

Comment: Depends on many things, your recusive query is a good way, try to merge  it with the query I proposed to you. I won't be able to help more. Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! You helped me so much!! :) I've marked your answer as minimal!